# I have a question about Star Wars Novels

Tags: star-wars

I am reading the Novels wrote on the Movies and I finish reading them what would be the first book you would read that was the first book made

Comment: Totally opinion; but the [Thrawn trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrawn_trilogy) is quite good. **But**, the first book was [Splinter of the Mind's Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splinter_of_the_Mind's_Eye) (per Wikipedia,  it was the first original full-length Star Wars novel to be published after the release of the 1977 Star Wars film, retroactively making it one of the earliest Expanded Universe works.)

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking for the first book written, it was Allen Dean Foster's *[Star Wars: From the Adventures of Luke Skywalker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_From_the_Adventures_of_Luke_Skywalker)* (credited to George Lucas, but actually written by Foster). It differs from the film because it was based on an early script rather than the one used in the movie. The first book that was not a novelization of the movies was *[Splinter of the Mind's Eye](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Splinter_of_the_Mind's_Eye)*, also by Foster, released between the first and second movies. Infamously, it includes a sexually-charged mud-wrestling match between Luke and Leia before Lucas decided that the two were siblings.

Comment: I have `Splinter of the Mind's Eye` at home (somewhere!), and from memory there is a little author's note in the back that tells the reader to keep their mind open to the possibility of some chemistry between Leia and Han.  So I suspect that story arc may have already been devised by this stage.

Comment: "I know. Somehow ... I've always known." Damn Leia, you knew and you still did all that. That's creepy.